# MySQL Cluster - Got error 1601 'Out extents, tablespace full' from NDB

Tags: mysql, mysql-cluster, tablespaces

I am trying to do some tests on MySQL Cluster.
I am creating my database using following commands:

```
CREATE DATABASE test1;
use test1;
CREATE LOGFILE GROUP lg1
ADD UNDOFILE 'undofile.dat'
ENGINE = NDB;
CREATE TABLESPACE ts1
ADD DATAFILE 'datafile.dat'
USE LOGFILE GROUP lg1
ENGINE = NDB;
CREATE TABLE `dane` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `data` blob NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
TABLESPACE ts1 STORAGE DISK
engine=ndb;
```

Then I populate table with some data and random blobs 50KB each. But I am getting following error:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO dane(id, data) VALUES(3790, randomBlob(51200));
ERROR 1114 (HY000): The table 'dane' is full
mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                |
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1296 | Got error 1601 'Out extents, tablespace full' from NDB |
| Error   | 1114 | The table 'dane' is full                               |
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from dane;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|     2507 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0,03 sec)
```

It is not cluster memory usage problem:

```
ndb_mgm> ALL REPORT MEMORYUSAGE
Connected to Management Server at: localhost:1186
Node 3: Data usage is 6%(164 32K pages of total 2560)
Node 3: Index usage is 7%(178 8K pages of total 2432)
```

2500*50KB ~= 1GB
I have this error any time I am trying to insert more than 1GB of blobs.
How I can extend size of this tablespace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First 2500*50kB ~= 128MB. Then if you will check [CREATE TABLESPACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-tablespace.html) syntax default INITIAL_SIZE for the datafile is 128MB!

So if you want to store more data you can either specify INITIAL_SIZE you need while creating tablespace or you can [ALTER TABLESPACE ADD DATAFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-tablespace.html).

By specifying `STORAGE DISK` in CREATE TABLE statement you stated that you want [on disk](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-cluster-disk-data.html) table not in memory. With such tables `ALL REPORT MEMORYUSAGE` shows nothing meaningful for that table.

If you want "classic" NDB table which is stored in memory just skip `TABLESPACE ts1 STORAGE DISK` modifiers and then `ALL REPORT MEMORYUSAGE` will show you how much memory is used for the data and indexes.

Comment: So tablespace is limited by initial size of file? Does is mean, that space on disk will be allocated for whole tablespace on creation time? (even if tablespace is empty)

Comment: Yes all INITIAL_SIZE is allocated on tablespace creation. Later you can extend tablespace with ADD DATAFILE statement. AUTOEXTEND_SIZE for now is silently ignored.
Once again - tablespaces are needed just for on disk tables. In memory tables do not need tablespaces at all.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword `INITIAL_SIZE` is misleading for both `CREATE TABLESPACE` and `CREATE LOGFILE GROUP`. It suggests that the file may autoextend on demand, but actually not.So `INITIAL_SIZE` is rather just `SIZE`.

There is nothing to do with `ALL REPORT MEMORY USAGE` here, since your table is created on disk (because of `CREATE TABLE .. TABLESPACE ts1 STORAGE DISK`). Only the `id` field you is stored in the memory (since  `PRIMARY KEY`).
I you are interested of the bytes free in tablespace, use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.FILES`, like

```
mysql> select FILE_NAME, FREE_EXTENTS*EXTENT_SIZE as bytes_free, extra  from   information_schema.FILES where TABLESPACE_NAME='ts_1' and    FILE_TYPE="DATAFILE";
+-----------+------------+----------------+
| FILE_NAME | bytes_free | extra          |
+-----------+------------+----------------+
| data1     |  132120576 | CLUSTER_NODE=3 |
| data1     |  132120576 | CLUSTER_NODE=4 |
+-----------+------------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

**Note:** Bytes_free is not increases if you `DELETE` from the table. The disk space is reclaimed only if doing `OPTIMIZE TABLE` after `DELETE` or if performing `TRUNCATE TABLE`.

**Note2:** For disk tables MySQL Cluster uses fixed row format, so `VARCHAR(10000)` is handled as `CHAR(10000)`. Using `BLOB` or `TEXT` is even more complicated: the first 256 bytes stored in the `DataMemory` and the rest is divided into 2k chunks, and stored in  a helper table. So inserting 5000 1k records into the above table, have a result like that

Before:

```
+-----------+------------+----------------+------------+
| FILE_NAME | bytes_free | extra          | row_format |
+-----------+------------+----------------+------------+
| data1     |  134217728 | CLUSTER_NODE=4 | FIXED      |
| data1     |  134217728 | CLUSTER_NODE=3 | FIXED      |
+-----------+------------+----------------+------------+

ndb_mgm> all report memory usage;
Node 3: Data usage is 2%(59 32K pages of total 2560)
Node 3: Index usage is 1%(26 8K pages of total 2592)
Node 4: Data usage is 2%(59 32K pages of total 2560)
Node 4: Index usage is 1%(26 8K pages of total 2592)
```

After:

```
+-----------+------------+----------------+------------+
| FILE_NAME | bytes_free | extra          | row_format |
+-----------+------------+----------------+------------+
| data1     |  123731968 | CLUSTER_NODE=4 | FIXED      |
| data1     |  123731968 | CLUSTER_NODE=3 | FIXED      |
+-----------+------------+----------------+------------+

ndb_mgm> all report memory usage;
Node 3: Data usage is 4%(120 32K pages of total 2560) 
Node 3: Index usage is 1%(42 8K pages of total 2592)
Node 4: Data usage is 4%(120 32K pages of total 2560)
Node 4: Index usage is 1%(42 8K pages of total 2592)
```

Disk usage

```
$> echo $(((134217728-123731968)/5000))
2097
```